# Google Auto ML , average precision

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-automl, average-precision

We used auto ml for multi label text classification. They use average precision as metric (the area under the precision-recall curve) but they didn’t mentioned if it is micro or macro or sample.Dose anybody know how they calculate average precision in google auto ml ?

Answer (score 0):

All evaluation metrics are **micro**-averaged in AutoML evaluations.